# Task scheduler stops running C# console application periodically

Tags: c#, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I have a task scheduler which runs a C# console application every minute. It runs the `.application` file via a `.bat` file and does so successfully for a period of time before stopping completely.

Un-installing/re-installing my console application doesn't fix the problem and the task scheduler is showing the batch file as succesfully executing. Also, running the program manually works just fine.

My questions are:

1. How can I get this task to run again via the task scheduler. I have tried deleting and re-creating the task, uninstalling/reinstalling the applcation.
2. I have a scheduled backup task occuring around the time the application stops working. Volume shadow copy is not enabled. Could this be impacting my application and why?

Comment: When you say stopping, you mean the tassk scheduler fails to start the process, or the process fails? If the later, what is the exit code? Can you include logging in the app to get some clues? Anything in your windows event log?

Comment: Backup could have something to do with it. What does your application do? Does your application use file IO?

Comment: You'll need to find out more.  Look in the Windows event log for messages.  Disable the backup task and describe what that did.  Implement AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell The process starts and launches the application with exit code 0. I have implementing logging in my application via NLog, however nothing is written to the log file during this time.

Comment: @MortenAnderson The application is an email, SMS and general workflow scheduler. It is a console application which performs routine tasks. I can disable the backup task but cannot get the app to run as a scheduled task again.

Comment: @Nick, if you put a Debugger.Launch() at the start of the process you will be able to attache a debugger and step through, try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the help, I did not manage to isolate the cause of this problem.

I have re-developed my scheduler using Quartz.NET and it's now running as a Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

In the task scheduler take a look at the Settings tab. You will find an option "If the task fails, restart every".

By default (this is not checked) then if your task fails it will not be run again. You can check your task history to see if it has failed. In any case it sounds like you want to be run again even if it failed the last time it ran.

This is the option you want to change.